# How to display proper UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: php, html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>тест</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

I have set the meta tag, but every time I open up the browser (Chrome), I have to go to `Tools -> Encoding` and set encoding on `UTF-8` in order to make it work.

Is there a way to avoid this step so browser displays proper UTF-8?

Comment: Please post the URL of the page. This will let us see the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your web server is probably sending a `Content-Type` header with a different `charset`. This will take precedence over your `<meta>` tag. Confirm this on the command line using `curl` (*nix system required):

```
curl -i http://example.com/yourpage.php
```

Look at the http headers at the beginning of the response and find the `Content-Type` header.

You can remedy this in a couple of ways:

1. Configure your web server (I'm guessing Apache) to send the appropriate charset. See [Apache docs for `AddDefaultCharset`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset).
2. Set the `Content-Type` header just in your script using the [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function. Like this:

   ```
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
   ```

   But make sure to put this call before any other output to the browser or else PHP will choke.

Answer (score 1):

The correct order is

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>тест</title>
```

Also include before any other output on the php code, and even before the embedd html:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: It's unlikely to make a difference. Although this is a good practice, modern browsers will tolerate any order.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a text editor to view your content try to see your enconding:
If the file enconding is different use this PowerShell script to change your enconding to UTF-8. After that you need to upload again your files into teh web server.

```
Get-ChildItem *.php -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
$content = $_ | Get-Content

Set-Content -PassThru $_.Fullname $content -Encoding UTF8 -Force}
```